# Wordpress backend delay by server side HTTP Request

Tags: plugins, optimization

I had 50 seconds of loading time for my backend in wordpress. I thought it was very strange for a DB to be so slow and I realized with the help of the Query Monitor plugin that the server is making some external curls. I deleted most of them but I'd like to disable also the following. Can you help me in my investigation?

POST (non-blocking)
http://www.***.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1446680141.8524429798126220703125

POST
http://api.wordpress.org/core/browse-happy/1.1/

POST
https://jetpack.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php?for=jetpack
&wpcom_blog_id=62253535